# How to make a form independent to another form?

Tags: forms, delphi, vcl

I have a VCL application with a small form class. It's just a normal form with below `FormCreate` event.

```
procedure TSmallForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FormStyle := fsStayOnTop;
  self.BorderStyle := bsNone;

  AlphaBlend := True;
  AlphaBlendValue := 50;
  self.Color := clRed;

  left := 100;
  top := 100;
  width := 15;
  height := 15;

  self.Show;
end;
```

I have a button on the main form. I create a small form when the user clicks the button.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  var f :=  TSmallForm.Create(nil);
end;
```

Everything seems work fine. But the problem is that when the user minimizes the main form, the small form also got minimized. How to always keep the small form on screen and not connected to the main form? Ideally I hope to put it always top most.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting WndParent to zero will do the trick in [CreateParams](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Alexandria/en/Vcl.Forms.TCustomForm.CreateParams):

```
type
  TSmallForm = class(TForm)
  private
    { Private declarations }
  protected
    { Protected declarations }
    procedure CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams); override;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  SmallForm: TSmallForm;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

{ TSmallForm}

procedure TSmallForm.CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams);
begin
  inherited;
  Params.WndParent := 0;
end;
```

To keep the form on top, set the `FormStyle` to `fsStayOnTop`.

Comment: Please note that this `WndParent` trick not only affects the "main form minimized" issue, but also the z-order behaviour: With this trick, the secondary form can be hidden beneath the main form (which would normally never happen). Setting `FormStyle` to `fsStayOnTop` causes a desktop-wide "on top" behaviour, which is far more aggressive than the "above the own app's main form" behaviour.